# Menu Drawer level up

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer for my app.
I works great, but I want to remove the level up action from the icon and the activity title in the actionbar.

Please note, that I am using `ActionBarSherlock` as well.

Does anybody know how I can remove this?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add in `onCreate` method

To remove title `getSupportActionbar().setTitle("")` , and `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected` for implement action to the Home Button

example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    getSupportActionbar().setTitle("")
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home || item.getItemId() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: to disable the home button, can do `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);`